# How can I show my Counter-Strike server in the "find servers" list?

Tags: hosting, counter-strike

I bought Counter-Strike ([the original](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10/)) from Steam, downloaded the game and opened it.

After doing so, I clicked on "Find Servers" and saw some listed servers there. I want to list my server here. I made a CS 1.6 server on my Cloud Server. How can I show my server on the Internet list on server explorer in the game?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure it's set up properly and you'll find it. Start a search for your server IP and you should eventually find your server. If not, read on...

Check/edit your `server.cfg`

- sv_lan 0
- sv_region [0-7 or 255] (see [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Sv_region) for details)

---

Remove bad stuff

- Bots
- Fake Spectators
- ...

---

Ports

- make sure port 27015 (TCP and UDP) is forwarded correctly

Comment: Thanks bro I will try and if works I will accept your answer.

Comment: How will I search my server ip?

Comment: Add it to your favs in the server browser (if it works there it works anywhere) or give it a unique name/map and look for that one.